# Create a 3D Route with SceneKit

Tags: plot, graph, routes, scenekit, bezier

I have a GPX file with locations and altitude data.
I would like to create a 3D model and show this model using SceneKit.

I already tried the method using a NSBezierPath, but the problem is, that I can not add the Z data and it is more like a 2D route.

Right now I am creating a SCNBox for every single trackpoint - well, it works but it's not really that pretty and it kinda seems wrong.

I also thought about creating a 3D model (obj file) programatically, but this is too hard.

So, long story short: What is the best way to create a 3D geometry object with SceneKit when I got a list of points with X/Y/Z data?

Is there a way to "connect" SCNBoxes?

Regards,
Sascha

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The question, as is, feels more like a "this is a question about best practices, which should be covered by tutorials" rather than a question about code that isn't working. While that's not always off-topic, it helps if you explain [what searching and researching you've already done](/help/how-to-ask) that makes you feel this is the right place to ask that question.

Answer (score -2):

Try the [SCNShape](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShape_Class/) class. It allows you to create a 3D shape following a bezier path while controlling the Z axis as well:

"SceneKit creates a three-dimensional geometry by extruding a Bézier path, which extends in the x- and y-axis directions of its local coordinate space, along the z-axis by a specified amount."

Comment: OP already noted, *"I already tried the method using a NSBezierPath, but the problem is, that I can not add the Z data and it is more like a 2D route."* All `SCNShape` does is extrude a 2D path to a uniform thickness; it doesn't create a 3D path.

Comment: OK. Noted. What about [SCNGeometryElement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNGeometryElement_Class/index.html) with  [SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeLine](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scngeometryprimitivetype/scngeometryprimitivetypeline) ?